# how do I find Accessibility size of iOS device

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I know in iOS one can change the font size of the device using accessiblity

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202828

How can I find the Text size that has been set in Acccessbility programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for any view controller's or view's `traitCollection`. The setting in question is the `preferredContentSizeCategory`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1771746-preferredcontentsizecategory

Comment: In real life, however, your app should simply adopt Dynamic Type so that it doesn't have to query the preferred content size directly. For a good intro, watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/